# How to filter collection of child entities in JPA 2?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have two entities in OneToMany relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id @GeneratedValue
public long id;

public String name;

@OneToMany
public Collection<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
...}

@Entity
public class Address {

@Id @GeneratedValue
public long id;

public String city;
...}
```

I want to fetch the employees with some simple criteria on employee fields(which is fine, not a problem) and it should contain only those addresses which has "New Delhi" in its city field(This is the problem).

Something equivalent to below in JPA 2

```
from Cat as cat
left join cat.kittens as kitten
    with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

This problem is the simplified version of my actual problem.

My main problem if much more complex, it has multiple child entities and filtering on the parent entity uses sql function.

Due to above reasons I cant use HQL or Native Queries.

So I'm looking for solution in "JPA 2 ONLY" using EntityManager , CtiteriaBuilder and all that.

Comment: 3.5 years later and this is still an issue ..

Comment: But this should normally work with JPQL `SELECT c FROM Cat c JOIN c.kittens k WHERE k.bodyWeight > :weight` This would fetch `Cat` with reduced collection of `Kitten`s just like RDBMS would.

Comment: @Antoniossss: No it does not. It will return the cat entity without filtering the child entities. See: http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.de/2012/04/objects-vs-data-and-filtering-join.html#Filtering

Answer (score 0):

Filtering relationships in EclipseLink JPA requires the use of native API. The way you do it is to create a [DescriptorCustomizer](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_customizer.htm#CHDCCDGC):

```
package ec.pack.z.pruebasDesarrollo;

import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression;
import org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionBuilder;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToManyMapping;

public class DC implements DescriptorCustomizer {
 @Override
 public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
  OneToManyMapping oneToManyMapping = (OneToManyMapping) descriptor.getMappingForAttributeName("addresses");
       Expression exp = oneToManyMapping.buildSelectionCriteria();
       ExpressionBuilder builder = exp.getBuilder();
       Expression addedExpression = builder.getField("city").equal("New Delhi");
       oneToManyMapping.setSelectionCriteria(exp.and(addedExpression));
 }
}
```

On entity:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Customizer;

@Entity
@Customizer(ec.pack.z.pruebasDesarrollo.DC.class)    
public class Employee {

@Id @GeneratedValue
public long id;

public String name;

@OneToMany
public Collection<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
...}
```

[Reference](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg07940.html)